# Returning Laravel validation errors to Ajax call

Tags: php, json, laravel

I'm trying to figure out how to pass back to my ajax call that there were validation errors if there is so that I can prevent the page from continuing on and display those errors to the user.

```
/*
* Create User After they complete the first part of the form. 
*
*/
public function createUserAndOrder(Request $request)
{
    $validation = $this->validate($request, [
        'first_name' => 'required',
        'last_name' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required|confirmed|unique:users,email',
        'email_confirmation' => 'required'
    ]);

    $credentials = [
        'first_name' => $request->input('first_name'),
        'last_name' => $request->input('last_name'),
        'email'    => $request->input('email'),
        'password' => Hash::make(str_random(8)),
    ];

    $user = Sentinel::registerAndActivate($credentials);

    $user->role()->attach(5);

    return response()->json([
        'success' => true,
        'errors' => null
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try it by using [`Validate`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#manually-creating-validators) Facade as:

```
$validator = \Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'first_name' => 'required',
    'last_name' => 'required',
    'email' => 'required|confirmed|unique:users,email',
    'email_confirmation' => 'required'
]);

// Validate the input and return correct response
if ($validator->fails())
{
    return response()->json(array(
        'success' => false,
        'errors' => $validator->getMessageBag()->toArray()

    ), 422);
}
```

This would give you a JSON response like this:

```
{
    'success': false,
    'errors': {
        'first_name': [
            'The first name field is required.'
        ],
        'last_name': [
            'The last name field is required.'
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: So you are definitely right. However I get this result. {"success":false,"errors":{"first_name":["The first name field is required."],"last_name":["The last
 name field is required."],"email":["The email field is required."],"email_confirmation":["The email
 confirmation field is required."]}}

"NetworkError: 422 Unprocessable Entity - http://myapp.app/createUserAndOrder"   What does that mean as an error.

Comment: The result is OK. You have to handle this in your ajax call. If the http status code is 422 then you can show the errors to the user returned from the server.

Comment: Oh okay do I do this in the success or error handler in the ajax call?

Comment: Well what's odd is if you reference back to my post before this it won't console.log() anything so that I can do that.

Comment: I am not sure why it's happening but you can check the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). And I prefer to use the this syntax for ajax calls - `$.ajax({...}).done(function( msg ) {...}).fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {...});`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128198/discussion-between-user3732216-and-amit).